# Class array initialization

Tags: c++, constructor, operator-overloading

Good morning. 
Question is about initialisation of object.
Its easy to do like this:

```
class MyClass {
  char* data;
public:
  inline MyClass(char* s) {
    data = s;
  };    
}

MyClass Obj = "foo";
```

But is it possible to make initialization syntax(with the same actions) like this?

```
MyClass Obj[] = "foo";
```

I need brackets for compatibility with other compiler :/

Comment: 1) does it work? 2) do you *need* an array? with one element? You call it "brackets", which suggest you have no idea what you're doing.

Comment: Your first sample is using a dangerous and deprecated feature or C++03: binding a non-const `char*` to a string literal. You should change `data` to `const char*`. As for the rest of the question, it isn't clear what you are after.

Comment: do you want to create an array with all elements default initialized to "foo"?

Comment: Forgot to write, char* data must be declared as const char* data. I want to create 1 object, with member data initialized by string "foo".

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the initialization list using {} ?

```
MyClass Obj[] = {"foo"};
```

or

```
MyClass Obj[] = {"foo", "bar"};
```

Comment: This wil not work with other compiler, it think that MyClass is a string. Okay more clarification. I have compiler data type like "new_char". If i want string it can be initialized only like: `new_char MyString[] = "foo"`. But for GCC i can't do `typedef char new_char`, because typedef its only synonym and GCC compiler dont make any difference between  "char" and "new_char". And i cant use some overloaded functions which operates only with "new_char" and must not work (throw an exception for example) with "char".